# Adding procedure labels to Objective-C and C code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode, crash

In the [second paragraph from the bottom of this post on reading crash logs](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10330727-263.html) the author mentions adding labels to the methods so that you can clearly see which task caused the crash.

How do you do this? Mind you I'm talking about C and Objective-C within XCode for the iPhone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric, what that article is referring to are the *symbols* of the application.

When you build a binary with Xcode, specifically for Archiving/Release, Xcode will create a separate "folder file" called *YourAppName*.dSYM.

The dSYM file is essentially a big list of memory addresses and the function/method calls in your application that correspond to them.

Any crash log you view in Xcode should then automatically go from memory addresses to symbols based on that DSYM file.

However, when you get a crashlog from iTunes Connect or from another user directly, you'll need to use `symbolicatecrash` on the command line to do this.  There are plenty of tutorials out there on this.